# How to get stable tip position in leap motion

Tags: c#, leap-motion

I am using Leap Motion SDK 3.2 to with my project in C#. I could get the Finger tip coordinates using finger.stabilizedTipPosition.

But the data that I get is continuos. I want the data to be displayed on the text box just when the finger if stable (not moving).

For the same, I wrote below code :

```
Vector tipVelocity = leapFinger.TipVelocity;
if (tipVelocity.Magnitude == 0.0)
{
    // Display the data on the GUI
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.x);
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.y);
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.z);
}
```

However, I still get continous values. Any suggestions ?

Comment: add language tag, improve code appearance

Comment: It seems that the stabilized position is always 0, which is the case when using v4 SDK (stabilized position is now deprecated). Can you please try with `finger.TipPosition`?